# Cycling Color Animation

Tags: c, animation

i want a way to cycle through white and black colors like an animation in c

here what i was using before

```
static void ChangeWordColor()
{
    if (color_cycle == 11)
    {
        color_cycle = 0;
    }
    switch (color_cycle)
    {
    case 0:
        updatecolor(0xFFFFFF);
        b4color = 0xFFFFFF;
        break;
    case 1:
        updatecolor(0xDCDCDC);
        break;
    case 2:
        updatecolor(0xD3D3D3);
        break;
    case 3:
        updatecolor(0xC0C0C0);
        break;
    case 4:
        updatecolor(0xA9A9A9);
        break;
    case 5:
        updatecolor(0x808080);
        break;
    case 6:
        updatecolor(0x696969);
        break;
    case 7:
        updatecolor(0x808080);
        break;
    case 8:
        updatecolor(0xA9A9A9);
        break;
    case 9:
        updatecolor(0xC0C0C0);
        break;
    case 10:
        updatecolor(0xD3D3D3);
        break;
    case 11:
        updatecolor(0xDCDCDC);
        break;
    }

    color_cycle++;
}

void FT_print_text_animate(uint dst_x, uint dst_y, int per, const char text)
{
    if (frame % per == 0)
    {
        //every while(1) loop is "per" so every 2 loop cycles it changes color
        ChangeWordColor();
    }

    FT_loop_text(dst_x, dst_y, text, 2);
}
```

i need a way to animate this maybe using delta time or a better method, maybe bit shifting for color
also this code uses ARGB, and updatecolor(); changes the FT pixel color.

i also need any solution to work in a loop ofc.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The use of a `case` statement is rather ugly and needless. Have a look at storing your color values in an array and using `color_cycle` as the index into the array. It will greatly simplify your code. You can also use the number of elements in the array as a divisor in a modulo `%` operation to allow _any_ value of `color_cycle`.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking for, and your code fragments are very incomplete.  I cannot even start to decipher _"every while(1) loop is "per" so every 2 loop cycles it changes color"_ ; what `while(1)`loop?  The _"what I was using before"_ - does it work - i.e do what you need?  And if not how does it fail to meet requirements?  Are you just asking for a "better" implementation of the same, or do you need to fix or change something?

Comment: @Clifford im referring to the main loop this function is in as this just draws the text, i need a better animation implementation , and yes it does work just isnt smooth enough

Comment: The "smoothness" is either down to the number and distance of your grey levels or the irregular timing of your switching - it is not clear what you mean in this context.  You seem to be asking about a number of other things that are not related to "smoothness".

Comment: What library am you usin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better perhaps to make the colour (or grey level in this case) update responsible for its own timing.  In the following it is only necessary to call the `FT_print_text_animate()` function at an interval somewhat faster than the required update interval - it handles its own timing, and changes the colour only when it is time to do so:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define GREY_LEVEL_CHANGE_PERIOD (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 5)    // Change five time per second (for example)

static void UpdateTextGreyLevel()
{
    // Levels to cycle back-and forth through
    static const uint32_t grey_levels[] = { 0xFF,0xDC,0xD3,0xC0,0xA9,0x80,0x69 } ;

    // Current grey index and direction through cycle
    static int cycle_index = 0 ;
    static int direction = -1 ;

    // Set current grey level
    uint32_t grey_level = grey_levels[cycle_index] ; 
    updatecolor( grey_level << 16 | grey_level << 8 | grey_level );

    // If it is time to change grey level....
    static clock_t last_change = 0 ;
    clock_t now = clock() ;
    if( now - last_change > GREY_LEVEL_CHANGE_PERIOD )
    {
        // Start new interval
        last_change = now ;

        // Change direction at either end of the cycle
        if( cycle_index == sizeof(grey_levels) - 1 || cycle_index == 0 )
        {
            direction = -direction ;
        }

        // Increment/decrement cycle index
        cycle_index += direction ;
    }
}

void FT_print_text_animate( uint dst_x, uint dst_y, const char text )
{
    UpdateTextGreyLevel() ;
    FT_loop_text( dst_x, dst_y, text, 2 ) ;
}
```

For example you may have a main loop:

```
for(;;)
{
    FT_print_text_animate(0, 0, "Hello!" ) ;
}
```

And the grey level will change at 200ms (in this example) intervals regardless. If you are "moving" the text also, then the determination of the position might use a similar *call rate independent* timing to update the position.

Essentially you call the function as fast as you are able, and let the function determine whether it is time to update anything.  In that way all your timings can be entirely independent of each-other and not reliant on any loop update interval.

To change the number and values of the grey levels, it is only necessary here to change the `grey_levels` array - everything else sorts itself out.

Comment: 2 problems  change `if (now - last_change > GREY_LEVEL_CHANGE_PERIOD)` to `if (now - last_change > CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 5)`

and

` ``static clock_t last_change = clock()`` ` gives  Error initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Comment: @user11611146 : first point, why? Second point - accepted, I generally code in C++, my error.  It was coded blind without testing it would compile, I'd be surprised if there were not other issues.  The take-home is the principle if call rate independent timing, rather than the precise code.

Comment: @user11611146 :. Also my error, the correction to the timeout test is more appropriately applied to the macro definition.  Again in C++ I'd have used a const clock_t rather than a macro.